# Add two items with different shipping methods to basket / checkout in drupal commerce

Tags: commerce, taxonomy-terms

I am currently using drupal commerce to build a
website for my partner who sells jewellery. I consider myself a fairly
confident drupal user and have built various websites using the platform.
This is the first time i have used commerce though.

So my issue is with shipping. I have three shipping package types defined in
a taxonomy, and a nice way to select which of these 3 package types the
product should be shipped by using a term reference field in product
creation. I have successfully got commerce to reference to this term
reference using Commerce Taxonomy Conditions. So far I have 3
shipping package types set up and 3 world zones and can get the correct
shipping cost associated to each of these options to come up fine in the
checkout pane.

So i have 9 shipping services (3 package types x 3 world zones)

BUT

The problem comes when there are two different package types (taxonomy terms)
added to the basket and therefore there should be two prices added together and in checkout it comes up with "No valid shipping rates
found for your order, and we require shipping service selection to complete
checkout."

How can I get this to work please? What am I missing?

I have tried OR and adding to that the taxonomy term which is true and the two taxonomy terms which are false and now i can get two package types displayed in shipping in the check out pane but not getting them adding together?

This is currently doing my head in, any help would be gratefully received. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, shipping is set on an order-basis. If you want to have per line-item shipping that would be something you'd have to build custom. Line items *are entities* so you can add new fields to them (including shipping profiles) and then create a shipping module or ruleset that properly configures shipping.